# Can I pick which meta data to use from photos to be able to use ALAssetsLibrary with location services off?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, location, alassetslibrary

I found that using ALAssetsLibrary gives an error when location services are disabled or not granted to my app.

I am using *enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:* and the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> This method will fail with error [ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError) if the user has not enabled Location Services (in Settings > General).

Is it possible to fine grain which meta data I am going to use from the photos, so I can still get them from the library? I actually don't need the location where the photo was taken.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible (yet? it's not possible in iOS 5.1)

The only way to access photos in the library without having the location warning is to present a UIImagePickerController, but obviously that doesn't help much for most projects where you need to display a custom gallery, or access more than one picture at a time.

Comment: I noticed my photos are not even saving any GPS data by default, so for me it's even more unclear why we MUST have location services enabled. Also noticed that, when using the default UIImagePickerController, the devices save the photos super fast, with all the meta data included.

Answer (score 0):

We have found that there is not location permission request in iOS 6. Maybe iOS 6 has other privacy control on Photos. So you don't need to asking location permission. Our solution is to check the [[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] and only using ALAssetsLibrary when iOS >= 6.